# Share generated GitHub Token within different jobs on GitHub actions

Tags: github, github-actions

The idea is to share token between jobs, in order to avoid duplicating
the step of the generated token,

1. any risks on doing so ?
2. Seems that I am losing the token
   value in the others jobs, any ideas?

```yaml
name: My Workflow
 
 on:   push:
     branches:
       - main
 
 jobs: 
   generate-token:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     outputs:
       token: ${{ steps.github-app-token.outputs.token }}
     steps:
       - name: Generate Github App access token
         id: github-app-token
         uses: tibdex/github-app-token@021a2405c7f990db57f5eae5397423dcc554159c
         with:
           app_id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
           private_key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
           installation_id: ${{ secrets.INSTALLATION_ID }}
       - name: Print access token
         run: echo ${{ steps.github-app-token.outputs.token }} 

    my-job:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     needs: generate-token
     env:
       APP_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ needs.generate-token.outputs.token }}
     steps:
       - name: Checkout code
         uses: actions/checkout@v2
       - name: Use Github API
         run: |
           curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $APP_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://api.github.com/user
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: An option could be to generate a new secret in the repository for each execution of the first job, then use the secret on the second job, and delete the generated secret from the first job on a third job (even if second job fails).

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes, this works for sure, but I didn't want to duplicate this step

Comment: Passing a secret value to.an output is dangerous. The receiving job won't know the value is secret and will log it to the logs. If you enable diagnostics logging the value will be logged prior to any step can mask it.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is why we are considering suggestions like add_mask option or encrypt decrypt between jobs

Comment: The idea of encrypting/ decrypting value is good, but look similar to using secrets. I wouldn't go for a customized solution due to security risks (as what @jessehouwing shared above). Create / Delete secrets during workflow execution may not look efficient or optimized, but it would at least be a bit more secure as using the own platform solution.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I am not creating/deleting secrets; this solution encrypts/decrypts the same token (not saying it's good either ), but due to our organization limitation, I was looking for a workaround with the minimum of a nasty code. 
But for now, the only solution is to duplicate the step of token generation; unfortunatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⚠️ Be VERY careful when passing secrets between jobs. The secret value will be visible in a number of cases, even if you apply the `::add-mask` command diligently. Even if you encrypt the value, it may not be easily accessible, but the encrypted value will be logged and can be intercepted.

In a number of cases the runner will even fail to set the output variable altogether, it will log a warning, but won't fail the build:

> ### build
>
> Skip output 'protect-this' since it may contain secret.

When a job runs in debug mode, even the first step will list all of the variables passed to it. They are logged in the debug logs plaintext and won't be retroactively scrubbed when you register the secret using `::add-mask` in the script itself.

Sample workflow:

```yaml
# ⚠️ BAD EXAMPLE. This workflow demonstrates you can't rely on output variables to pass secrets.
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  ACTIONS_RUNNER_DEBUG: true


jobs:
  build:
    outputs:
      environment: ${{ steps.environment-selector.outputs.environment }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run a one-line script
        id: environment-selector
        run: |
          echo "environment=prod" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo '::add-mask::prod'          

  deploy:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     needs: build
     steps:
     - name: Run a multi-line script
       run: |
          echo '::add-mask::${{ needs.build.outputs.environment }}'
          echo ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment }}
```

In the debug logs:

```
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Run a multi-line script'
##[debug]Evaluating: success()
##[debug]Evaluating success:
##[debug]=> true
##[debug]Result: true
##[debug]Starting: Run a multi-line script
##[debug]Loading inputs
##[debug]Evaluating: format('echo ''::add-mask::{0}''
##[debug]echo {1}
##[debug]', needs.build.outputs.environment, needs.build.outputs.environment)
##[debug]Evaluating format:
##[debug]..Evaluating String:
##[debug]..=> 'echo ''::add-mask::{0}''
##[debug]echo {1}
##[debug]'
##[debug]..Evaluating Index:
##[debug]....Evaluating Index:
##[debug]......Evaluating Index:
##[debug]........Evaluating needs:
##[debug]........=> Object
##[debug]........Evaluating String:
##[debug]........=> 'build'
##[debug]......=> Object
##[debug]......Evaluating String:
##[debug]......=> 'outputs'
##[debug]....=> Object
##[debug]....Evaluating String:
##[debug]....=> 'environment'
##[debug]..=> 'prod'                         <<<< SECRET LOGGED AS PLAINTEXT
##[debug]..Evaluating Index
```

⚠️ Even if you encrypt the secret using GPG or another tool, the encrypted text will be stored for anyone to see and could be reverse engineered. You can't hide the text safely.

⚠️ Most auth-related actions will inject a post-job script which will revoke the token as soon as the job finishes. So you can't rely on a token to survive the job.

Comment: ok thanks @jessehouwing for the example, I need to find another solution for my workflow, but indeed add-mask not secured to pass sensitive data

Answer (score 0):

Your job `my-job` is missing the `needs` keyword. In order to use the output from a previous job you need to specify that `my-job` depends on `generate-token` by using [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds). Only then can you use `${{ needs.generate-token.outputs.token }}`. Also I would suggest re-ordering your job in your workflows fail it will make it easier to understand.

Comment: You are right, I've changed the order; thank you for the tip 
I also added the needs that I missed while writing this question, but I had on my environment, the token was empty on the second job

Comment: I think the output was disable due to security concerns,
I had this message
Warning: Skip output 'token' since it may contain secret.

Comment: @hb.Sara the token is empty or masked?

Comment: Not empty and not masked

Comment: Here is a full example that might help https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-usage-of-the-needs-context

Comment: @ITChap the issue here is not needs field, its the fact token is sensitive data,
I've added   echo "::add-mask::$GITHUB_TOKEN", I don't have a warning anymore but the second job doesn't pickup the value still

Comment: @hb.Sara The fact that you can't echo or display the token is indeed related to github masking feature. But the  `APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` should still contain your token. You can also try to use `${{ needs.generate-token.outputs.token }}` directly in your curl command without the env variable to see if it's related to this.

Comment: I think when job outputs with masking leads to empty output

Comment: @ITChap I"ve tried using ${{ needs.generate-token.outputs.token }} directly but the toekn is still empty 
because of the following error

Evaluate and set job outputs
Warning: Skip output 'token' since it may contain secret.
Cleaning up orphan processes

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (but not sure if I will actually use it) a solution proposed in this [article](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-pass-secrets-between-runners-in-github-actions/)

1. Create a secret with pass phrase is mandatory
2. Adding a step on Job one as following

```
        - name: Set outputs
          id: set_outputs
          run: |
              echo "token=$(gpg --symmetric --batch --passphrase "$SECRET" --output - <(echo "${{ steps.generate_token.outputs.token }}") | base64 -w0)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          env:
            SECRET: ${{ secrets.PGP_SECRET_SIGNING_PASSPHRASE }}
```

3. and to use the token or secret on the second job

```
$(gpg --decrypt --quiet --batch --passphrase "$SECRET" --output - <(echo "${{ needs.generate-token.outputs.token }}" | base64 --decode))
```

PS, I had an issue with the expirationdate, but this is another problem